# Grandchild files?

Tags: input

I am using `\input` to include the various parts of a paper (literature review, research design, analysis, conclusion), each of which are a separate file.

I also have subsections within some parts, including the review; each subsection is also a separate file. I have `\input` the subsection files into the section files, which are then `\input` into the main file. The section (child) files are inputting fine, but the subsection (grandchild) files are creating an error.

Is the error caused by the `\input` within a child file? In other words, is it possible to have grandchild files in this setup?

Comment: `\include` cannot be nested but `\input` can...
Maybe you need to strip down your document to the minimal portion that shows the issue and post it here...

Comment: Please add an MWE. `\input` can usually be nested, it is `\include` which cannot be invoked recursively (see [When should I use \input vs. \include?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) )

Comment: No MWE is necessary: I was just making sure it is possible. The problem was that the child (and grandchild) files were in a different folder than the main file, but the relative paths to the grandchild files (within the child files, which are all in the same folder) did not take into account the fact they were in a different folder from the main file.